# How do I resume after handling a SIGPFE signal?

Tags: c, signals, libc

I have this short c program that deliberatly causes a SIGPFE and tries to handle it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void catch_floating_point_error(int signal_number) {
  printf("I caught a floating point error\n");
}

int main() {
   signal(SIGFPE, catch_floating_point_error);

   for (signed int i = -3; i<=3; i++) {
     printf ("30 / %d = %d\n", i, 30/i);
   }
}
```

When I compile and execute this program, it prints

```
30 / -3 = -10
30 / -2 = -15
30 / -1 = -30
I caught a floating point error
I caught a floating point error
I caught a floating point error
...
```

until I terminate the process with ctrl-c.

I expected that the program would resume with the execution one instruction *after* the instruction causing the FPE after executing the signal handler `catch_floating_point_error`.

This is apparently not the case. It seems that the program is re-doing the failing instruction again.

So, how can I skip the failed intstruction when I was notified that I had a SIGFPE?